# winecfg purely via terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, wine, staging

Could not find the answer here, neither elsewhere.

Is there a way how to use and control winecfg via terminal only? winecfg always pops up a window, but I wish to set the preferences via terminal only (operating system and staging options).

The alternative for me would be a config file with preferences which I can edit.

Thanks for replies

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the note. My purpose is to make bash script automatizing winetricks and wine configuration - I figured that was sort of development related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [winecfg](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg):

```
 Winecfg is a GUI configuration tool for Wine, designed to make life a little easier than editing the registry.
```

You can modify the registry by hand using your favorite editor. I don't know of any tools that work as gui inside the terminal for editing the wine registry. Wine stores registry under `$WINEPREFIX/*.reg`, probably in `~/.wine/*reg`.

Comment: Thanks, modifying registry is enough for me.